# Connecting Laravel (with Valet) with Sequel Pro, how do I problem solve?

Tags: laravel, laravel-valet

I've successfully got my Laravel application working from a git pull, however connecting to a Sequel Pro (MAMP) database is proving difficult.

Here's the error

> InvalidArgumentException in compiled.php line 11774: Database [] not configured

Is it because I need to run SQL within the specific laravel installation?

Followed by:

> in compiled.php line 11774
>   at DatabaseManager->getConfig(null) in compiled.php line 11739
>   at DatabaseManager->makeConnection(null) in compiled.php line 11702
>   at DatabaseManager->connection(null) in compiled.php line 11578
>   at Model::resolveConnection(null) in compiled.php line 11565
>   at Model->getConnection() in compiled.php line 10972
>   at Model->newBaseQueryBuilder() in compiled.php line 10963
>   at Model->newQueryWithoutScopes() in compiled.php line 10950
>   at Model->newQuery() in compiled.php line 1026
>   at EloquentUserProvider->retrieveByCredentials(array('email' => 'henry.xxx@xxx.com', 'password' => 'xxx')) in compiled.php line 611
>   at SessionGuard->attempt(array('email' => 'henry.xxx@xxx.com', 'password' => 'Henry1301budon7a'), false) in compiled.php line 2477
>   at AuthController->login(object(Request))
>   at call_user_func_array(array(object(AuthController), 'login'), array(object(Request))) in compiled.php line 9424
>   at Controller->callAction('login', array(object(Request))) in compiled.php line 9486
>   at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(AuthController), object(Route), 'login') in compiled.php line 9466
>   at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request))
>   at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
>   at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in RedirectIfAuthenticated.php line 24
>   at RedirectIfAuthenticated->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
>   at call_user_func_array(array(object(RedirectIfAuthenticated), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in compiled.php line 9963
>   at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request))
>   at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
>   at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request))
>   at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in compiled.php line 9948
>   at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 9467
>   at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(AuthController), object(Route), object(Request), 'login') in compiled.php line 9454
>   at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController', 'login') in compiled.php line 8524
>   at Route->runController(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8511
>   at Route->run(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8225
>   at Router->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request))
>   at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
>   at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in HttpsProtocol.php line 15
>   at HttpsProtocol->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
>   at call_user_func_array(array(object(HttpsProtocol), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in compiled.php line 9963
>   at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request))
>   at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
>   at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 3225
>   at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
>   at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in compiled.php line 9963
>   at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request))
>   at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
>   at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 13474
>   at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
>   at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in compiled.php line 9963
>   at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request))
>   at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
>   at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 11964
>   at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
>   at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in compiled.php line 9963
>   at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request))
>   at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
>   at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 13213
>   at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
>   at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in compiled.php line 9963
>   at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request))
>   at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
>   at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 13150
>   at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
>   at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in compiled.php line 9963
>   at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request))
>   at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
>   at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request))
>   at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in compiled.php line 9948
>   at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 8226
>   at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8217
>   at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8207
>   at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 2419
>   at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http{closure}(object(Request))
>   at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
>   at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 3286
>   at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
>   at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in compiled.php line 9963
>   at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request))
>   at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
>   at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request))
>   at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in compiled.php line 9948
>   at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 2366
>   at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 2350
>   at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
>   at require('/Users/henry/sites/nestdb2017/public/index.php') in server.php line 158

And this is my .env file:

```
APP_ENV=localwg
APP_KEY=base64:qzPgRKOqqbVN86K27CNKEPkBjPTKnXaFGs7ubsHtAYg=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://nestdb.local
APP_TIMEZONE = Asia/Hong_Kong

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=nestlaravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=

MY_HOST=nestdb.local
PRODUCTION_SERVER=1
HOST_ROOT=http://nestdb2017.test/
```

Can you see what the problem might be?

Comment: What does your config/database.php look like?

Comment: Yes exactly! That was the issue - it was missing! Literally 2 mins before you posted that I realized that, fixed it and that was the solution!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that I was missing the config/database.php file (which oddly was not pulled down from git - perhaps security?)